# How to remove an element from a set within a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

I have trouble removing an element from a `set` within a `map` called `accesrightsByRank`. The keys of the maps are different `ACCESRIGHT`s : `owner`, `modify`, `read` and `none`. The values of the `map` are `set`s with names of accessors with certain `ACCESRIGHT`s.

```
    map<ACCESSRIGHT, set<string>>::const_iterator i;
    set<string>::const_iterator j;

    for(i = this->accessrightsByRank.begin(); i != this->accessrightsByRank.end(); i++){
        for(j = (*i).second.begin(); j != (*i).second.end(); j++){
            if( (*j).compare(p_Username) == 0){
                i->second.erase(j);
            }
        }
    }
```

I thought `i->second` would give me the `set` from which I could erase the username who no longer has a certain `ACCESRIGHT`, but it seems I did something wrong. Could someone explain to me why this doesn't work and how I should adjust my code?

This is the error I receive:

> IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "`std::set<_Kty, _Pr, _Alloc>::erase` [with `_Kty=std::string`, `_Pr=std::less<std::string>`, `_Alloc=std::allocator<std::string>`]" matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match)
>               argument types are: (`std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::string>>>`)
>               object type is: `const std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::string>>`

Comment: `const_iterator` yields `const set<string>&` as `second`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki why not answer?

Comment: You're defeating the whole purpose of `map` and `set` if you need to do a linear search, just saying....  You should be using `set::find`, not a linear search.

Comment: `(*i).second` is the same as `i->second`. The latter is preferred.

Comment: You should post the error message. Chances are it already answers your question.

Comment: @nwp: The OP should learn the lesson of `const_iterator`, *then* throw this code away and use multimap.

Comment: @Beta no, I was actually wrong, a map of sets could be appropriate in this case as one needs to find stuff in the set. A relational database is probably better still.

Comment: @n.m.: ??? Isn't that what `multimap::equal_range` is for? (I admit I haven't worked much with multimap, but I'd be very surprised if it couldn't do that.)

Comment: @Beta he needs to search in the set of *values*, not keys.

Comment: @n.m.: He wants to search for a given value *within the range of a given key.* He could iterate over the range (in a multimap) given by `equal_range`, which would be better than his code above, but you're right, a map of keys to sets would be cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by [Piotr Skotnicki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3953764/piotr-skotnicki) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315478/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-set-within-a-map-in-c#comment52505956_32315478), you are using a `const_iterator`. The name alone indicates that such iterator does not permit changing the thing it's pointing to. Change these lines:

```
map<ACCESSRIGHT, set<string>>::const_iterator i;
set<string>::const_iterator j;
```

to this:

```
map<ACCESSRIGHT, set<string>>::iterator i;
set<string>::iterator j;
```

for the quickest fix. However after this, do consider all the advices from the comments under the question.

Comment: Further, dissecting the error messages indeed demonstrates this as root-cause, as the object type: `const std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>` proclaiming there is no viable `erase` method confirms this analysis.

Comment: Thank you for all the advice, I will certainly keep it in mind! But @BartoszKP,  I think you meant changing `map<ACCESSRIGHT, set<string>>::const_iterator i;` to `map<ACCESSRIGHT, set<string>>::iterator i;` because a set only allows the use of const_iterators.

Comment: @Laura. Indeed - you need to change both. See my update.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize all the comments,

1. You are modifying the map and the set. Thus you should use `iterator`, not `const_iterator`.
2. To erase some value in a set, you don't need linear search. `std::set::erase()` has a variant that takes the value to be deleted.
3. `i->second` is equivalent to and easier to read than `(*i).second`.
4. `this->` is redundant except if you have a local variable with the same name.

Combine them, you will get

```
map<ACCESSRIGHT, set<string>>::iterator i;

for(i = accessrightsByRank.begin(); i != accessrightsByRank.end(); i++){
    i->second.erase(p_Username);
}
```